# Javascript date formatting to local timezone with specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have a date string which is in UTC timezone like this `2015-05-26T14:02:46.000Z`

I will convert this to a date object using

```
var lastModified = "2015-05-26T14:02:46.000Z;
var date = new Date(lastModified);
```

But when I print this, it prints the date like this `Tue May 26 2015 19:32:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I want to print the date like this `2015-05-26 7:32:46 PM IST` or `2015-05-26 7:32:46 PM GMT+0530`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: This syntax is invalid. You are missing a comma at the end of lastModified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hindmost says, it's pretty simple in pure JS. But if you'll be doing this a lot, you may want to look into the powerful [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) library.

Using Moment, your code would just be:

```
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A [GMT]Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

Date has a number of getter method to get the components of a date. For example `date.getHours()` will return a number from 0 to 23 for the hour of the day. With each of these pieces you can write the logic to display the date in the format you choose. See the methods `Date` has here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

If you're looking for a library, [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is the best library I've used for time and dates. It might be too heavy for your needs though. Consider use cases carefully before adding another somewhat large dependency.